# Retrieve MSSQL datetime2(7) value as Python datetime with microseconds rounded instead of truncated

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

If I do a `CAST` in T-SQL, `0397` is rounded to `040` with proper rounding, but pyodbc truncates it to `039`. How can I easily do this rounding like SQL Server does it?

```
1> select logid, timestamputc from eventlog where logid=166944;
2> go
logid                timestamputc
-------------------- --------------------------------------
              166944            2017-05-30 08:59:37.6650397

1> select logid from eventlog
where cast(timestamputc as datetime2(6))='2017-05-30 08:59:37.665039';
2> go
logid
--------------------
(0 rows affected)

1> select logid from eventlog
where cast(timestamputc as datetime2(6))='2017-05-30 08:59:37.665040';
2> go
logid
--------------------
              166944
```

with pyodbc:

```
[{'logid': 166944, 'timestamputc': '2017-05-30 08:59:37.665039'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, when pyodbc retrieves a `datetime2(7)` column as a Python `datetime` object its default behaviour is to truncate the seventh decimal place. If you want the `datetime` object to be rounded, as SQL Server would return a `datetime2(7)` value CAST to `datetime2(6)`, then you can use an [output converter function](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Using-an-Output-Converter-function).

For example, if you define your output converter function as

```python
def handle_datetime2(dt2_value):
    tup = struct.unpack("<6hI", dt2_value)  # e.g., (2017, 5, 30, 8, 59, 37, 0, 665039700)
    return datetime(tup[0], tup[1], tup[2],
                    hour=tup[3], minute=tup[4], second=tup[5],
                    microsecond=math.floor(tup[6] / 1000.0 + 0.5))
```

and use it like this

```python
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str, autocommit=True)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

cnxn.add_output_converter(pyodbc.SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, handle_datetime2)

dt_string = '2017-05-30 08:59:37.6650397'
dt_value = crsr.execute(f"SELECT CAST('{dt_string}' AS DATETIME2(7))").fetchval()
print(f'{dt_string}\n -> {repr(dt_value)}')

dt_string = '2017-05-30 08:59:37.6650395'
dt_value = crsr.execute(f"SELECT CAST('{dt_string}' AS DATETIME2(7))").fetchval()
print(f'{dt_string}\n -> {repr(dt_value)}')

dt_string = '2017-05-30 08:59:37.6650394'
dt_value = crsr.execute(f"SELECT CAST('{dt_string}' AS DATETIME2(7))").fetchval()
print(f'{dt_string}\n -> {repr(dt_value)}')
```

the results will look like this

```
2017-05-30 08:59:37.6650397
 -> datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 30, 8, 59, 37, 665040)
2017-05-30 08:59:37.6650395
 -> datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 30, 8, 59, 37, 665040)
2017-05-30 08:59:37.6650394
 -> datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 30, 8, 59, 37, 665039)
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent example. I will test this out. Is there not a simple way to just remove the last 100nano digit from datetime2(7) without rounding inside mssql. In oracle I just set the NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT and everything is autoconverted.

Comment: In mssql You can do this: `cast(left(timestamputc, len(timestamputc)-1) as datetime2(6))`

Comment: I already have a converter for the datetime type using ```connection.add_output_converter(pyodbc.SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, datetime_as_string)```. How to differentiate output_converters for datetime and datetime2(6)?

Comment: @DirkR - You don't need to. Microsoft's ODBC driver returns the fractional seconds as nanoseconds regardless of the datetime2 precision value.

Comment: @GordThompson "I don't need to". Sorry this doesn't help me. I get an error on ```tup = struct.unpack("<6hI", dt2_value)``` if I run this handler against datetime columns. I use ```struct.unpack("<2l", value)``` for datetime handling and ```struct.unpack("<6hI2h"``` for datetime2. The only way I can do this at the moment is trying the one, and trying the other if it errors. Hence my question.

Comment: @Dirk - My apologies for mis-reading your question. If both column types come back as `pyodbc.SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP` then your approach makes sense: Attempt the `unpack` for `datetime2` in a`try` block and if it fails then retry for a `datetime` payload.